# Xcode icon / launch screen catalogs with empty images

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, submission

I have an old project (xcode 6) which is using icons and launch images by naming (placed in the root folder and added them through the info.plist).

The thing is, I would like to start using xcode catalogs for icons and launch images but I realized I don't have many of the assets they are requesting in those catalogs.

I was thinking in just filling the ones I have, but I'm afraid Apple will reject my version once I upload it to the itunes. Anyone knows if you can just leave empty images?

Answer (score 0):

Use this - "Migrating Your Images to an Asset Catalog" Xcode will give you warning for all missing icons based on your deployment target

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH28-SW5

Comment: The thing is i don't want to have to provide all the missing assets as it would increment my bundle size

Comment: i don't think that's optional. you need to provide required icons based on deployment target

Comment: But right now, with placing the assets in the folder with the correct resolution, i don't need to provide all the missing cases. In fact, I have a very few icons there (4), when the asset catalog requires like 10